# Tradução da palavra portable referindo-se a uma linguagem de programação

Tags: terminologia, cross-platform

Em Computação, na língua inglesa, usa-se o adjetivo `portable` para qualificar uma linguagem de programação que pode ser facilmente usada em diferentes plataformas, permitindo que um mesmo programa seja executado nestas plataformas sem necessidade de alteração do código fonte.

Como a expressão `portable language` é melhor traduzida para o português neste contexto?

**Editado:**
Esta dúvida é sobre terminologia de conceitos de programação e acho que pode se encaixar no tópico *dúvidas teóricas sobre conceitos e práticas aplicados ao desenvolvimento de software*. No entanto se for considerada *off-topic* aqui, não sei qual fórum poderia ser mais apropriado.

Comment: **Linguagem portável**. Eu pelo menos não vejo dificuldade no entendimento em se traduzir assim.

Comment: Eu também pensei nesta tradução, porém não encontro no dicionário um significado para `portável` que se encaixe no contexto. No Aurélio encontro ¹ 1. Diz-se da obrigação ou dívida que se tem de pagar no domicílio do credor. 2. Diz-se do pagamento que assim se faz.  ² 1. Que se pode portar ou levar.

Comment: @romildo A segunda definição dá conta do recado. Algo que se pode portar ou levar de um lugar para outro é exatamente a idéia de portabilidade.  Não espere encontrar termos técnicos em dicionários comuns.

Answer (score 3):

Uma `portable language` se trata de uma linguagem que oferece suporte a várias plataformas. Uma possível tradução, partindo desse contexto, seria `linguagem com suporte a várias plataformas`.

Comment: +1 - Essencialmente correto. Um termo derivado: [linguagem multiplataforma](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplataforma).